# Shell Sort Algorithm

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to implement an array using the shell sort algorithm. The program will sort the array and output each element to the Listbox after the button was clicked. However, the first item output is always 0. I have included a piece of my source code and a photo of the form below;

```
 Dim randGen As New Random()
    Dim unstArray() As Integer
    Dim unstArrayCopy() As Integer
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 'Generates random number to save in array.
        Dim i As Integer = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
        ReDim unstArray(i)
        ReDim unstArrayCopy(i)
        For x = 0 To i
            unstArray(x) = randGen.Next(1, 10001)
        Next
        Array.Copy(unstArray, unstArrayCopy, i)
    End Sub

 Private Sub ShllSrtBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles shllSrtBtn.Click
        shellsort(unstArrayCopy, unstArrayCopy.GetUpperBound(0))
    End Sub

    Sub shellsort(ByRef shellSort() As Integer, ByVal max As Integer)
        Dim stopp%, swap%, limit%, temp%, k%
        Dim x As Integer = CInt((max / 2) - 1)
        Do While x > 0
            stopp = 0
            limit = max - x
            Do While stopp = 0
                swap = 0
                For k = 0 To limit
                    If shellSort(k) > shellSort(k + x) Then
                        temp = shellSort(k)
                        shellSort(k) = shellSort(k + x)
                        shellSort(k + x) = temp
                        swap = k
                    End If
                Next k
                limit = swap - x
                If swap = 0 Then stopp = 1
            Loop
            x = CInt(x / 2)
        Loop
        For i = 0 To shellSort.GetUpperBound(0)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(shellSort(i))
        Next i
    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You need to debug your code. You generally don;t fix bugs simply by reading code or looking at the end result. You need to use the debugger, i.e. set breakpoints and step through the code and examine the state at each step. When the state differs from what you expect, you have found the issue and you have something concrete to investigate. If the state never differs from your expectations then it's your expectations that are at fault.

Comment: You are aware that the line "Dim i As Integer = CInt(TextBox1.Text)" creates one more integer than what is in TextBox1.Text, aren't you?  It goes from 0 to TextBox1.Text, not TextBox1.Text number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
    ReDim unstArray(i)
    ReDim unstArrayCopy(i)
```

In VB, when you initialize an array, you must give it the maximum index you want to use, not the intended array length as in other languages like C#.

Because of that, your code creates an array of length i+1, but you only loop from 0 to i when filling the array.  So the last element at index i will always be zero.

You should set the initializer in these lines to i-1.

[VB Array Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/)

Comment: I'm not sure what the initializer is. @Sean Skelly

Comment: My bad.  Change `ReDim unstArray(i)` to `ReDim unstArray(i-1)`, and same for the other array.  The key in all this, though, is to understand _why_ this is necessary, which has to do with 0-based indices and VB's quirk of wanting the maximum index and not the length when initializing an array with a specified number of elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am encountering an error.  @Sean Skelly

Comment: @NAN Can you post more about the error?  I suppose I forgot to mention that you should handle the special case where the user chooses 0 for the value of i.

Comment: The For loop in the first Sub says "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' "

Comment: @NAN: ah.  The `For` loop also loops on indices, the way you have written it.  So it should loop from 0 to `i-1` as well.  Note that the call to Array.Copy does expect a length, and not the maximum index, so that line should use `i`.